# How to concatenate data and delete columns across multiple rows and columns?

Tags: excel, vba, iteration, concatenation

I have a macro that's designed to check whether the strings "Doc1" and "Doc2" appear in consecutive columns all along the first row (header).
The macro should then, for all subsequent rows, concatenate  information in the Doc1 column with that  from the Doc2 column and separate the responses with a comma. It should then delete the entire Doc2 column.
With the code I have, this works for the first instance of Doc1 and Doc2 side by side.  For the rest of them, it simply deletes the Doc2 column without concatenating the info into the Doc1 box.  Any help on this would be greatly appreciated.

Here is the *code*:

```
Sub test()

Dim CurrCol As Integer
Dim NewValue As String
Dim CurrRow As Integer

CurrCol = 1
RowNum = 1

'set last cell
While Cells(1, CurrCol).Address <> "$HOK$1"

    'MsgBox Cells(1, CurrCol).Address & " " & Cells(1, CurrCol).Value

        If InStr(Cells(1, CurrCol).Value, "Doc1") > 0 Then
            ' look at next cell
            If InStr(Cells(1, CurrCol + 1).Value, "Doc2") > 0 Then
                For i = RowNum + 1 To 10
                    If Trim(Cells(RowNum + 1, CurrCol + 1).Value) <> "" Then
                        NewValue = Cells(RowNum + 1, CurrCol).Value & ", " & Cells(RowNum + 1, CurrCol + 1).Value
                    '   MsgBox "New Value is " & NewValue
                        Cells(RowNum + 1, CurrCol).Value = NewValue
                        RowNum = RowNum + 1
                    End If

                Next


            End If

            'now delete currCol+1
            Range(Columns(CurrCol + 1), Columns(CurrCol + 1)).Select
            Selection.Delete Shift:=xlToLeft

        End If


    'Advance the counter
    CurrCol = CurrCol + 1
Wend

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue you're having looks to be with line `RowNum = RowNum + 1`. This line is unnecessary and is causing your RowNum variable to be off after the first column. Instead, use the i variable to reference which row you are currently on. If you only want to loop from row 2 to 10 (which is what appears to be the case) you need to make the following adjustments:

Change this:

```
If InStr(Cells(1, CurrCol + 1).Value, "Doc2") > 0 Then
    For i = RowNum + 1 To 10
        If Trim(Cells(RowNum + 1, CurrCol + 1).Value) <> "" Then
            NewValue = Cells(RowNum + 1, CurrCol).Value & ", " & Cells(RowNum + 1, CurrCol + 1).Value
        '   MsgBox "New Value is " & NewValue
            Cells(RowNum + 1, CurrCol).Value = NewValue
            RowNum = RowNum + 1
        End If

    Next

End If
```

To this:

```
If InStr(Cells(1, CurrCol + 1).Value, "Doc2") > 0 Then
    For i = 2 To 10
        If Trim(Cells(i, CurrCol + 1).Value) <> "" Then
            NewValue = Cells(i, CurrCol).Value & ", " & Cells(i, CurrCol + 1).Value
        '   MsgBox "New Value is " & NewValue
            Cells(i, CurrCol).Value = NewValue
        End If
    Next i
End If
```

Comment: @user2108977 Click the checkbox next to my answer.